# How should I define contrast with more than 2 levels in DESeq2?

Tags: r

I would like to do differential expression analysis using DESeq2 while my contrast has more that 2 levels! I faced the problem which was how to define it in result function. How should I define this type of factors with many levels?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use "name" argument in "result" function which is the name of the individual effect (coefficient) for building a results table. Use this argument rather than contrast for continuous variables, individual effects or for individual interaction terms.